# Cannot compare string read from file and from keyboard

Tags: c, string

Same as the title, i have a file with this format. First i read the number and then the string. The problem is i cannot compare str with the string s "ABCD", the strcmp function should return 0, it instead returns 1. 
And i also want to compare str with a string input from keyboard (s1), let say "ABCD" as well.
Thanks in advance

```
void main()
{
    char s[] = "ABCD",str[100],s1[190];
    int i;
    FILE*fi;
    fi = fopen("fi.txt","r");
    fscanf(fi,"%d",&i);
    fgets(str,255,fi);
    scanf("%s",s1);
    printf("%d\n",strcmp(s,str));
    system("PAUSE");
    /*this is my fi.txt file: 
    1
    ABCD
    */
}
```

Comment: @user3078414 what do you mean?

Comment: @user3078414 No, the first line is a number, the 2nd line is the string

Comment: See [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359)

Comment: Why `255` with `char str[100]; fgets(str,255,fi);`?

Comment: Are you sure this is a duplicate? This problem described seems to be in the _leading_, not the trailing newline, staying in the `stdin`  buffer since previous `fscanf()`, even before the `fgets()` getting called?